# Extract XML payload from http inbound gateway and supply to xslt transformer spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have requirement wherein I need to expose a restful service with XML payload. After that I need to get hold of xml payload and transform it to different xml using xslt transformer.

I am struggling how to get hold of xml payload that can act as a input to the xslt transformer.

I want to avoid marshelling and unmarshlling overhead.

Can someone please help me on same.

Regards
Lalit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions like this, it's better if you show what you have tried and what didn't work.

In this case, all you need is an [HTTP Inbound Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-inbound).

If the incoming `content-type` contains text; the payload will be `String`, by default. If not (e.g. `application/xml`) then you'll need to configure the gateway with the type you want...

```
request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
```

otherwise, the payload will be a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks Gary for response.... I think you have given me a very important clue.... about byte[]..... Now I got my problem solved... Thanks a lot again

Comment: Gary, can you please suggest how I can access headers and payload both... as I want to do following tasks as part of chain 1) extract authentication info from header 2) validate xml 3) transform

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, it is customary here to mark the answer as 'accepted' (check/tick mark under the votes). It helps other users searching for similar issues. You should really ask another question rather than piggy-backing on this one. However, see the [documentation about header mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping); if you still have questions, ask another one.

Comment: I think the problem is solved....... I will ask my other question as a different post otherwise it will mix two things....

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gary's suggestion... used following code and it worked...

```
<int:channel id="inputChannel"></int:channel>

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="inputChannel" path="/test" supported-methods="POST">
    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/xml" produces="application/xml" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="sa1"></int:service-activator>
    <int-xml:xslt-transformer
        xsl-resource="classpath:/testTransformer.xsl"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="sa2"></int:service-activator>   
</int:chain>

<!-- input type is byte[] -->
<bean id="sa1" class="com.fidintl.integration.ServiceActivator1">
</bean>

<!-- input type is String -->
<bean id="sa2" class="com.fidintl.integration.ServiceActivator2"></bean>
```

It looks like in post (as Gary mentioned) output is byte[] which I converted to string in ServiceActivator1

Regards,
Lalit Kumar